# how to keep duplicate values when using split method in java

Tags: java, split

I've a string that consists of duplicate values.I'm using split() method to split it into substrings.The problem is split() returns array of different values and i need to retain duplicate values.how to achieve this?

Comment: can you show us some inputs ?

Comment: split returns all the values and doesn't remove duplicates. Can you provide an example of what you are doing?

Comment: Definitely using `String.split()` not some other `split()` method we don't know about? Because as others point out `String.split()` does not work that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

split doesn't remove dupliates. It returns an array not a set.

```
String text = "dup dup dup dup dup dup dup dup";
String[] parts = text.split(" ");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

prints

```
[dup, dup, dup, dup, dup, dup, dup, dup]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a HashSet like this:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
Collections.addAll(set,yourString.split(**split parameter**));
```